# SQL primary key is wrong for assignment.. not sure what I did wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, key

I copied this example from a website for a quiz

: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/movie-database-exercise/index.php

I got these questions wrong when the professor looked over the DB.. not sure why

```
-2 -- Movie_cast missing PK
-2 -- movie_direction missing PK
-2 -- movie_genre missing PK
-2 -- rating missing PK
```

This is my database diagram

[image]

Not sure what I did wrong..  I'm not good at SQL

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

As your professor has said, every table in a database needs an identifier. This identifier is known as the **PRIMARY KEY** or **PK**.

To clarify, every row in a table will have a specific attribute or set of attributes by which you can identify that specific row. Those attributes are the **PRIMARY KEY** of the table.

It can be as simple as an integer index with auto increment, or even a combination of columns from that table. **FOREIGN KEY** columns can also be part of your **PRIMARY KEY**.

You need to define the **PK** for the tables you mentioned above, that'd be all.